# Android emulator: restore from snapshot freezes emulator

Tags: android-emulator, qemu, kvm

When using the Android emulator on Ubuntu 12.04 with emulator-x86, starting it from a snapshot causes the emulator to be unresponsive.

If I log in with adb shell and do `input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME` for example, the command takes up to 2 minutes to complete. After that, the emulator is responsive.

Is there a way to get more debug output to see why this is happening, would it be because of insufficient RAM/CPU resources?

Comment: If you solved your problem, I'm interesting in a solution :)